# sql - select row id based on two column values in same row as id

Tags: sql, t-sql

Using a `SELECT`, I want to find the row `ID` of 3 columns (each value is unique/dissimilar and is populated by separate tables.) Only the `ID` is auto incremented.

I have a middle table I reference that has 3 values: ID, A, B.

- A is based on data from another table.
- B is based on data from another table.

How can I select the row ID  when I only know the value of A and B, and A and B are not the same value?

Comment: For what database?  TSQL means either Sybase or Microsoft SQL Server.  Version would help too.

Comment: Are you trying to join three tables together?

Comment: is ID the same as ROW ID or are you looking for the row number ? Are you looking for distinct rows or rows where a and b are different ? What are all the plusses rewarded for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that columns A and B are foreign keys?

Does this work?

```
SELECT [ID] 
FROM tbl 
WHERE A = @a AND B = @b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE A=value1 and B=value2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear. Do you mean this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM middletable
WHERE A = knownA
  AND B = knownB
```

Or this?

```
SELECT ID
FROM middletable
WHERE A = knownA
  AND B <> A
```

Or perhaps "I know A" means you have a list of values for A, which come from another table?

```
SELECT ID
FROM middletable
WHERE A IN
        ( SELECT otherA FROM otherTable ...)
  AND B IN
        ( SELECT otherB FROM anotherTable ...)
```

Comment: great examples, but the obstacle here is I do not know the value of A nd B while I SELECT x amount of rows. The only way I know around this is by using a loop with variables which I do not want to do.

Comment: @user719825: In the question you say you know A and B. Here you say the opposite. If you can't provide the table structure with some data and the output you want, you'll get no help. No one can guess what's in your mind.